# Переход на мультиязычном сайте MODX

Tags: php, modx

Привет.

Как можно реализовать следующее?

Есть мультиязычный сайт например `test.nl` на сайте мы переходим на какую то страницу, пускай это будет страница `test`, итого мы на странице `test.nl/test`.

И когда будучи на этой странице мы например выбираем переход на испанскую версию напр. `test.sp`, то чтобы переход был на туже страницу но менялся только домен.

То есть тут выбрали испанинский язык `test.nl/test` и перевело на `test.sp/test`.

Сайт на MODX. В нем разбираюсь базово и по этому есть сложность с данной реализацией.

Буду благодарен за любую информацию.

Answer (score 0):

Так как сайты на разных доменах, то врядли такое получиться. Если бы сайт был на одном хосте и реализована мультиязычность через плагин, то другое дело.